# Getting Typescript strictNullChecks to work with undefined returning vanilla js functions

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

With idiomatic js returning undefined on error, converted to TS

```
function multiply(foo: number | undefined){
   if (typeof foo !== "number"){
      return;
   };
   return 5 * foo;
}
```

When using multiply in new TS code i get the problem of the compiler believing doStuff can return undefined, when it cannot.

So i tried to write an "unsafe" version of this function called by safe TS code, leaving the safe version for regular js code.

```
function unsafeMultiply(num: number){
   return multiply(num);
}
```

Since unsafeMultiply can only accept a number, the type guard in multiply should consider that multiply will only return a number since unsafeMultiply can only process number. 
If this is too complicated for the compiler, how do i force him to accept i know what i'm doing ?

Comment: *"With idiomatic js returning undefined on error..."* Citation needed. :-) That's not idiomatic in my experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When using multiply in new TS code i get the problem of the compiler believing doStuff can return undefined, when it cannot.

Yes, it can: `multiply(undefined)` returns `undefined`.

> If this is too complicated for the compiler, how do i force him to accept i know what i'm doing ?

You can do a type assertion, since you know that `multiply` will only return `undefined` if it is called with a non-number:

```
function unsafeMultiply(num: number) {
   return multiply(num) as number;
}
```

Or you can add code for a type guard at runtime:

```
function unsafeMultiply(num: number) {
  let result = multiply(num);
  if (typeof result === "undefined") {
    throw new Error("Invalid num argument");
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

But if it were me, I'd make the `multiply` function fail or return `NaN` rather than returning `undefined`, if given `undefined`. Then `unsafeMultiply` wouldn't be needed.

Comment: "But if it were me, I'd make the multiply function fail or return NaN rather than returning undefined, if given undefined"

The thing is this code is used by vanilla js code which is waiting for this code to return undefined if it doesn't work. Changing his return signature would brake too many thing.
Why do you think returning NaN would be better ?

Comment: @VincentJ your actual function is probably not that one, so it's hard to say for your actual function. But for multiply, calling this function with anything other than a number is an error of the caller, and returning NaN if the caller tries to multiply a non-number is clearer to me than returning undefined. Anyway, the caller should suffer the consequences of the error. Specifying that the function accepts undefined also looks weird to me: why would anyone want to multiply undefined?

Comment: I had to add undefined to the parameter or TS was complaining that the argument was a number and so the type check was not needed. Still this problem of mixing vanilla js code and typescript strict null check code.

Comment: @VincentJ - I said "fail **or** return `NaN`". :-) My reasoning is that in both cases (failing -- throwing an error -- or returning NaN), the return type of the function is `number`.